# How can I delete a group of posts that my app created?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

My app sent out a batch of posts tonight that were created erroneously.  I would like to delete them, but I don't currently store the ids of posts that I create.

Is there a way to query for posts made after a certain time?

Once I have the ids I think I know how to delete them.

I'm using the Ruby gems facebooker2 and mogli.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the posts from [`feed`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed) or [`home`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home) connection of [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

For using those connections to read users post you will need `read_stream` permissions from user (which may be a bit problematic in your case if you not yet have this permission granted) and active `access_token` (this one will be needed to remove the posts too).

- `feed` connection can be easily parsed to get posts from your application (since every [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) object have `application` property containing *name* and *id*)
- `home` connection contain much more details to parse but you can filter results by application using `filter` (like `/USER_ID/home/filter=app_2305272732`).

Once you discovered the posts you may delete 'em by issuing `DELETE` request to Graph API:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID?access_token=...
```

Or several posts for same user:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=POST_ID_1,POST_ID_2,POST_ID_N?access_token=...
```

**Notes:**
Since you said you didn't stored ids of post that published, more problematic may be discovering the list of users who got  posted.

Comment: I actually do have the list of users.  However, this approach requires the read_stream permission.  Is there no way to access these posts as an administrator of the app?